# Scraping web page and finding titles of rows

Tags: web-scraping, artificial-intelligence, puppeteer

I am looking for a way of finding titles for rows within a web page.

Using **Puppeteer** I could find rows titles in cases that I know the names of div's and classes. 
But what if I do not?
What if I would like to get all titles of any list that will appear?

Not looking for a full solution (If so, better) but even an idea of what technology I could use (Some kind of AI maybe) to get to this output.

Example:

[image]

Output:

1. Sekiro: Shadows Die Twice
2. Mortal Kombat 11
3. F1 2019
4. Outer Wilds

Comment: Maybe something like `h2,h3,h4,[class*=title]`

Comment: Actually you will need to train some AI to understand what is a title and what is not. Computers won't automagically know which one we are expecting as output. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Supervised learning

In case you mean something like a supervised learning AI system (like a neural network), I want to give you an idea of the problems you are going to face. There are three main problems:

**Training data**

To create an AI that automatically detects titles, you first need to train the AI. You will need hundreds, probably thousands of samples to train your AI. This means, you have to put a lot of manual work of getting and labeling input data before your AI can predict anything.

**Input for your AI**

What would you give as input to the AI? You have two options:

- The source code: This would basically train your AI to become a web browser. Fun challenge, but I doubt you will get any results at all out of this.
- A screen capture of the website? You should not feed the actual screenshot into the AI but instead try to "clean" it. For example, you could replace all texts with some kind of placeholder, as you want your AI to work on the "looks of the document" and not on the text itself. This approach will work better than the first one, but you will have to put some work into the cleaning of the image before it is given to your AI. This *could* work, but you need a lot of training data for this to reliably work.

**Reliability**

Even if you solve all problems and your AI is finally able to detect titles of lists, you need to be aware that an AI will never perfectly work. Of course, no algorithm will be perfect, but using an AI, you cannot simply "tweak" your algorithm to get better results.

Imagine, you see that for a specific website your AI does not work. You cannot debug your AI easily and adjust your code to make it work for that page. You will have to retrain your AI hoping that after your adjustments it will work. Maybe, then it will work for that page, but now another website will not work anymore...

### Algorithmic approach

Instead of using an AI, I recommend to use a simple algorithm to detect a list with heading elements inside. Something like the following could work:

Repeat the following for each heading tag (`h2`, `h3`, ...)

1. Get all heading elements (e.g. `h2`)
2. Is the number of elements <= 1, then this is not a list (skip)
3. Check the "surrounding elements" for each element. If this is a list, all elements should have the same surroundings: Do the parents of the elements have the same class name? Do the sibling nodes have the same classes? If not, this is not a list (skip)
4. Given the previous steps, the elements are very likely part of a list and your heading element should contain the title of the list.

There are some obvious drawbacks: This approach only works for a list of more than one element and only works if markup is correctly used. If the website is only using `div` elements instead of heading tags, this will not work. So, this should only serve as a starting point, the algorithm could obviously be improved...